# How to reverse a for loop in a Django template and then slice the result

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template, I'm iterating over a set of photos, and displaying them one by one. Specifically, right now I just have one photo set, containing 6 objects. I display these 6 objects like so:

```
{% for pic in picstream.photo_set.all reversed %}
    <img src="{{ pic.image_file.url }}"></img>
{% endfor %}
```

Adding `reversed` to the statement gives me the 6 objects in the desired ordering (i.e. the latest ids first).

Next, I want to display not more than 4 objects from the `photo_set`. I added `|slice:":4"` to `picstream.photo_set.all` to achieve this. Problem is, it's cutting off the first two objects *from my desired oredering.*

It seems there ought to have been a way to reverse the list **first**, and slice **later**? Need a simple way to do this, without performance compromises.

Comment: The template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic.

Comment: If slice does support all the syntax then you could use something like: `|slice:"::-1"|slice:":4"` which is first reversing the queryset and then getting top 4. But I am not sure if it is a good practice or not or even about its effeciency.

Comment: This doesn't belong to your template. While |slice':4' will result in limit 4 query on the database end because QuerySet object are lazy evaluated in Django having the list reversed will trigger the full query without limit and then slice a potentially big resultset in python putting too much strain on both your db and app server unnecessarily.

Comment: @KárolyNagy: what's your best suggestion to deal with this scenario? Including an illustrative example and writing that as an answer helps. I want the best way to do this, and will accept the answer that provides that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the `reversed` argument for the `for` template tag, you can use the `reverse` method of the queryset itself:

```
{% for pic in picstream.photo_set.all.reverse|slice:":4" %}
    <img src="{{ pic.image_file.url }}"></img>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are evaluating the original (non-reversed) queryset somewhere else in your code then this will result in a second query hitting the database. If this is the case then you are better off moving the logic into your view code itself or into a template tag.

Comment: Do note that for using `reverse` there already must be defined some ordering either on the queryset or on the model itself otherwise it wouldn't have any effect. Check the last paragraph [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#reverse)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am assuming there is some default ordering defined at model/queryset level otherwise the OP would not be interested in reversing it :-). Also, it will still work even if there isn't... just that the ordering is arbitrary either way.