# Reverse comments list in descending order to get the last n (2) objects in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've searched a lot and couldn't find anything to reverse the comment's list in descending order so that I can get the last two comments of each post in the template.

Here is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

**views.py:**

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("date_posted").reverse()
return render(request, "cs50gram/explore.html", {"posts": posts})
```

**template.html:**

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all|slice:":2" reversed %}
        <div style="color: gray">
            <b> {{ comment.commented_by }} </b>
                {{ comment.comment }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem here is that it slices first and then reverse..

What have I tried?
[How to reverse a for loop in a Django template and then slice the result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978715/15432055)

Using the solution presented in the answer, it didn't work for some reason. This is exactly how I tried it in my code.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all.reverse|slice:":2"%}
        <div style="color: gray">
            <b> {{ comment.commented_by }} </b>
                {{ comment.comment }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The output is that it only slice it without reversing.

Any help in reversing the comment's list in descending order and getting the last n (2) comments of each post is appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0):

for reverse order just add `-` sign to order_by value:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by("-date_posted")
```

Comment: Will that give me the comments list in reverse order? I doubt...